# frequent bug in UI (tabbar pushed from navigation)

Tags: iphone, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, tabbarcontroller

I have encountered this bug several times. I have a application with a navigation controller (navbar hidden). when a button is "pressed" i want to push another view with a tabbarviewcontroller. When the new view is pushed, it's 20 pixels lower than it should (and part of the tabbar is not visible).

If I enter modal-view controller from the tabbarviewcontroller and then i dismiss it, the tabbarviewcontroller is shown properly.

I put the status bar in every view to be unspecified (thought that was the problem) and i un-checked the autoresize subviews from each view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your code use bounds property instead of application frame . in my it worked hope to work in case too.......:)

Comment: 2. if u hiding status bar and then navigation bar then at the time of showing do opposite means show navigation bar first then status bar

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like it *might* be related to a known NIB/XIB file bug (for more information see: http://forums.bignerdranch.com/viewtopic.php?f=51&t=125)

As the linked forum topic suggests, for a workaround simply use the following:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    CGRect appFrame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
    [[self view] setFrame:appFrame];
}
```

Comment: didn't work ... yet. Anyway I'm only getting this when i push a tabbar from a navcontroller (happened in 3 app's till now).

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your answers. i did it somehow, playing with the tabbar's frame a bit.

```
[self.tabBarController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460)];    
[self.view addSubview:tabBarController.view];
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:tabBarController.view];
```

i remember trying this a while ago and not working. now it did.
also, medling with bounds helped a bit.